# How can I retrieve data from mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

This code is from our user login profile for our SAD project. The account I register for user log in is working since it saved in the database but I can't log in because it says invalid.

```
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(myconn);
            string query = "select * from southpoint_school.user where userUsername='" + textBox1.Text + "' and userPassword='" + textBox2.Text + "'";
            conn.Open();
           cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

       MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            count++;
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
            conn = new  MySqlConnection(myconn);

            string problem = "SELECT userAccountType from southpoint_school.user WHERE userUsername ='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(problem, conn);
            string answer = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            conn.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Login successful!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            if (answer == "Administrator")
            {
                memorable = "Administrator";

                frm_main main = new frm_main();
                main.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                memorable = "Limited";

                frm_main main = new frm_main();
                main.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
        else if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Username and/or Password Found!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username And/Or Password!");
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: `it says invalid` actually *your code* reports it as invalid.  Set a breakpoint and debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case

> Invalid Username And/Or Password!

can only happen when you have 0 ore more than 1 search results in your `southpoint_school.user` database with your entered username + password. So I would inspect the data in your database.

Additionally I would

- use parameters instead of string-concatenation for creating sql statements to avoid injection
- save (salted)hashed passwords instead of plaintext in your database
- use using statements for more effecient ressurce useage
- query the user-table only once and use the result twice

e.g.:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Username and/or Password Found!");
}
else
{
    DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
    string Command = "select * from southpoint_school.user where userUsername=@un and userPassword=@up";
    using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {

        using (MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command, myConnection))
        {
            myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@un", textBox1.Text));
            myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@up", textBox2.Text));
            myDataAdapter.Fill(dtResult);
        }
    }
    if (dtResult.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login successful!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if ((string)dtResult.Rows[0]["userAccountType"] == "Administrator")
        {
            memorable = "Administrator";
            frm_main main = new frm_main();
            main.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            memorable = "Limited";
            frm_main main = new frm_main();
            main.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
    else if (dtResult.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username And/Or Password!");
    }
    else //TODO: treat the case for multiple results
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: still it says Invalid Username And/Or Password

Comment: Then you have 0 ore more than 1 search results. Did you check the Data in your Database?

Comment: then i would debug, set an breakpoint and check the value of dtResult